# Help with song lyrics pronunciation （我的新衣）?

Tags: pronunciation, songs

So I was listening to the song "我的新衣” by Vava, and at a point the rapper Ty sings. And for some reason in this verse走到街上就像一千台进口奔驰 instead of 街 I listen he raps kāi. Can someone please tell me what he raps? Is it maybe some local accent and that's why I'm not hearing him pronouncing 街（jiē）properly? Thanks!

Comment: It is just dialect

Comment: If you listen closely - in the same line 像 is also pronounced qiǎng - another feature of Chengduese.

Comment: In my home town（江苏泗洪）, 街 is pronounced as gāi（not kāi）, rather than jiē.

Comment: Thank you so much you are all so helpful 

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation is most likely from a topolectical influence. If you check [Wiktionary's entry on「街」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A1%97), for example:

---

[image: screenshot showing pronunciations in Mandarin, Cantonese, Hakka, Min Bei, Min Dong, Min Nan and various topolects]

---

EDIT: as @user3306356 has noted, the rapper is speaking/rapping/singing in a topolect of Chengdu.

Comment: Seems like it’s exactly Chengduese. Genius (https://genius.com/artists/Ty-china/bio) says: Ty. (唐溢) is a Chinese rapper from the Chengdu-based rap collective Chengdu Rap House (说唱会馆).

Comment: There’s also this note on the lyrics page (https://genius.com/15340567): Ty delivers his verse in Sichuanese, a dialect very different from Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: And another note from Genius’s lyrics page (https://genius.com/15340567): Translation: I’m from Chengdu, and that’s Chengdu’s blessing, what you’re hearing is more than music, it’s also truth and facts

Ty is from Chengdu (Sichuan Province), and he’s saying that Chengdu has given him to the world, which the world should be thankful for, because he offers more than just music as a Sichuanese hip-hop artist

Comment: Thank you all very much!